# Roslyn and a .NET less C#?

Tags: roslyn

Roslyn is written in C# with some initial bootstrapping. Does it pave the way for a day when we don't need .NET for c#? Maybe a version of C# with a ".NET" runtime that is so small that we do not even consider it ".NET"?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: There is nothing in the C# spec that requires .Net. You (or anyone else) can write a C# compiler that does not target .Net. But I'm not sure why would you want to do that. Also, I don't see how does the language the compiler is written in have to do with this.

Comment: @svick: I think what he's getting at is that Roslyn "paves the way" in that it makes it much easier to write C# or VB compiler. But that's not our *intention* of the Roslyn project. Making it easier for compiler writers might be a happy side effect, but our general scenario is for improving the tooling around the existing compilers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Roslyn is written in C# with some initial bootstrapping. Does it pave the way for a day when we don't need .NET for c#?

I note that StackOverflow is not a good place to ask questions that require predictions of the future. I'll therefore confine my remarks to the present.

The purpose of the Roslyn project is to make it easier for people to do lexical, syntactic and semantic analysis of C# and VB programs. If you want to use the Roslyn lexical, syntactic or semantic analyzers to make a compiler that compiles C# for some other runtime, I suppose you could do that, but that's not one of our key scenarios for the project. We expect that most people will be using Roslyn to do analysis of programs that run on .NET.

Comment: The really interesting things come out when someone dares to go outside of supported key scenarios and do something different. ( And we (your clients) always do ;) )

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the Roslyn objectives. I would love to see C# "everywhere" and hence the question. :)